# Define custom properties before the creation of objects

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'm writing an add-on that will create a pattern of multiple objects (precious stones), there will be many stones of different sizes and I want to be able to define the sizes (user input) and the type of pattern from a predefined list.

The problem is that I have noticed that all the addons I can possibly copy from...
they create the objec(s) first AND THEN let you define its properties via "redo last" menu.

I also want to define all the stones sizes and keep them in some sort of database or list when the user starts modeling and use them later when they are needed, and if for some reason the user saves the file without creating any objects, be able to save that information.

Please explain the steps, I'm learning the bpy Api and its hard to find good information...
[image]

```
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name": "Baguette Pattern",
    "author": "Max Villafranca",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 79),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh > New Object",
    "description": "Creates and Aligns Tapered Baguettes",
    "warning": "This addon is in initial development stage",
    "category": "Object",
    }


import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
#from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty
from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper, object_data_add
from mathutils import Vector


##### BAGUETTE CREATION SECTION

def create_baguette(self, context):

    Lenght = self.Lenght
    Width_Top = self.Width_Top
    Width_Bottom = self.Width_Bottom
    Depth = self.Depth

    a = (-Width_Top/2,Lenght/2, 0)
    b = (Width_Top/2,Lenght/2, 0)
    c = (-Width_Bottom/2,-Lenght/2, 0)
    d = (Width_Bottom/2,-Lenght/2, 0)

    verts = [Vector(a),
             Vector(b),
             Vector(c),
             Vector(d),
            ]

    edges = []
    faces = [[0, 1, 3, 2]]

    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name="Baguette")
    mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
    # useful for development when the mesh may be invalid.
    # mesh.validate(verbose=True)
    object_data_add(context, mesh, operator=self)


class OBJECT_OT_add_object(Operator, AddObjectHelper):
    """Creates a bunch of Tapered Baguettes"""
    bl_idname = "max.add_baguette"
    bl_label = "Add Mesh Baguette"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    Lenght = bpy.props.FloatProperty (
                                        name = "Lenght",
                                        default = 2.5
                                        )

    Width_Top = bpy.props.FloatProperty (
                                        name = "Width_Top",
                                        default = 1.5
                                        )

    Width_Bottom = bpy.props.FloatProperty (
                                        name = "Width_Bottom",
                                        default = 1.0
                                        )

    Depth = bpy.props.FloatProperty (
                                        name = "Depth",
                                        default = 1.5
                                        )

    def execute(self, context):

        create_baguette(self, context)
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Your Pattern has been Layed")

        return {'FINISHED'}




####### PANEL CREATION SECTION

class BaguettePatternPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Baguette Pattern"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_context = 'objectmode'
    bl_category = 'Baguettes'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object


        row = layout.row()
        layout.operator("max.add_baguette", "Create Baguette Pattern", icon = "QUIT")

        row= layout.row()
        #layout.prop (bpy.props.FloatProperty, name = "baggy")


##### REGISTRATION


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
    bpy.utils.register_class(BaguettePatternPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(BaguettePatternPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Why do you think having your add-on work in a different way than all the other Blender add-ons is a good thing? As an aside, you may want to check [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and adjust the way you name things. By using a standard naming convention you'll make it easier for others to understand your code and help you out.

Comment: I will sure take your comment into consideration.